# MariaDB table with UUID primary key as BINARY(16) NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, mariadb, primary-key

I want to use BINARY UUIDs as my primary key in my tables, but using my own custom functions that generates optimised UUIDs loosely based on this article: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiduuid-performance/

The table structure and two main functions of interest here are:

```
CREATE TABLE `Test` (
  `Id` BINARY(16),
  `Data` VARCHAR(100)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';

CREATE DEFINER = 'user'@'%' FUNCTION `OPTIMISE_UUID_STR`(`_uuid` VARCHAR(36))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
/*
FROM

00       10        20        30
123456789012345678901234567890123456
====================================
AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE


TO

00       10        20        30
12345678901234567890123456789012
================================
CCCCBBBBAAAAAAAADDDDEEEEEEEEEEEE
*/
RETURN UCASE(CONCAT(
        SUBSTR(_uuid, 15, 4), /* Time nodes reversed */
        SUBSTR(_uuid, 10, 4),
        SUBSTR(_uuid,  1, 8),
        SUBSTR(_uuid, 20, 4),  /* MAC nodes last */
        SUBSTR(_uuid, 25, 12)));
END;


CREATE DEFINER = 'user'@'%' FUNCTION `CONVERT_OPTIMISED_UUID_STR_TO_BIN`(`_hexstr` BINARY(32))
    RETURNS BINARY(16)
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
/*
Convert optimised UUID from string hex representation to binary. If the UUID is not optimised, it makes no sense to convert
*/
RETURN UNHEX(_hexstr);
END;
```

I cannot use my custom functions in column definition as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE `Test` (
  `Id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT CONVERT_OPTIMISED_UUID_STR_TO_BIN(OPTIMISE_UUID_STR(UUID())),
```

I get the error "Function or expression '`OPTIMISE_UUID_STR`()' cannot be used in the DEFAULT clause of `Id`"

So I tried using the same in Triggers:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'user'@'%' TRIGGER `Test_before_ins_tr1` BEFORE INSERT ON `Test`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (new.Id IS NULL) OR (new.Id = X'0000000000000000') OR (new.Id = X'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF') THEN
    SET new.Id = CONVERT_OPTIMISED_UUID_STR_TO_BIN(OPTIMISE_UUID_STR(UUID()));
  END IF;   
END;
```

The above works pretty good, but the issue is that I cannot define the `Id` column as PRIMARY KEY, which I want to because PRIMARY KEYs have to be NOT NULL, and setting this means I have to pre-generate optimised UUIDs. I do not want to do this as I would like the DB to take care of generating the optimised UUIDs.

As you might have inferred looking at the above Trigger definition, I tried setting a default value on the `Id` column, such as:

```
Id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT X'0000000000000000'
```

and

```
Id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT X'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'
```

and

```
Id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' /* I tried setting 0, but always seem to revert to '0' */
```

and this default value would be picked up by the trigger and a correct optimised UUID assigned. But that also does not work as the DB complains "Column 'Id' cannot be null" even though a DEFAULT value has been set.

So my actual question is: Can I generate a custom (optimised UUID) BINARY value for a PRIMARY KEY column?

Comment: The [uuid datatype](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/) in MariaDB-10.7+ is already optimized for storage/searching for the UUIDv1 type. Also see discussion on [MDEV-29959](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29959) for other types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's doable even without triggers and/or stored functions:

**MariaDB from version 10.6**:

Use function `SYS_GUID()` which returns same result as UUID() but without `-` characters. The result of this function can be directly converted to a 16-byte value with UNHEX() function.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a BINARY(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT UNHEX(SYS_GUID()) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT);
SELECT HEX(a) FROM test;
+----------------------------------+
| HEX(a)                           |
+----------------------------------+
| 53EE84FB733911EDA238D83BBF89F2E2 |
| 61AC0286733911EDA238D83BBF89F2E2 |
+----------------------------------+
```

**MariaDB from version 10.7** (as mentioned in danielblack's comment):

Use `UUID` datatype which stores UUID() (and SYS_GUID()) values as 16 byte:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a UUID not NULL default UUID() PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (DEFAULT);
SELECT a FROM test;
+--------------------------------------+
| a                                    |
+--------------------------------------+
| 6c42e367-733b-11ed-a238-d83bbf89f2e2 |
| 6cbc0418-733b-11ed-a238-d83bbf89f2e2 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Addendum: If you are using a version < 10.6 and your requirements match the following [limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid_short/), you could also use `UUID_SHORT()` function, which generates a 64-bit identifier.

Comment: My `'sID' varchar(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT (uuid())` is not working in MariaDB 10 and if I define a table this way I can no longer edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes

Long answer:

The `PRIMARY KEY` can be almost any datatype with whatever values you can create.

- `TEXT` or `BLOB` are not allowed.  Not even `TINYTEXT`.
- `VARCHAR` (etc) are not allowed beyond some size (depends on version and `CHARACTER SET`).  `VARCHAR(191)` (or smaller) works in all combinations.  The ubiquitous `VARCHAR(255)` works in many situations.

MySQL 8.0 has builtin functions for converting between binary and string UUIDs.  This also provides functions (like yours) for such: [*UUIDs*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid)